# How to access DisplayMember from within a method of the same class?

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I have a Class Data  which has a protomember ReportName defined with a slightly different display name so that the grid column headers are more meaningful .

Now i am implementing IDataErrorInfo to this class to display an error message to the end user saying  'Report Name cannot be null' while saving . So how do i access the display member attribute of ReportName in a private method of the same class?

```
Class Data
{        
     [ProtoMember(1), DefaultValue(null), DisplayName("Report Name")]
     public string ReportName { get; set; }

     //Check if the reportname was entered
     private void CheckReportName()
     {
     //code to check reportname and generate the errormessage containing the colheader to be sent to grid 
     }
}
```

Ho

Comment: (Removed protobuf-net tag - not pb related)

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection:

```
var displayName = this.GetType()
    .GetProperty("ReportName")
    .GetCustomAttributes(false)
    .OfType<DisplayNameAttribute>()
    .First()
    .DisplayNameValue;
```

Comment: just curious here , will reflection slow down the performance as this code will be in the setter which would be fired for all cols and all rows in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Reflection already requires a 'magic string' for the property name to look up the value, you might consider something like this instead:

```
class Data
{        
    [ProtoMember(1), DefaultValue(null), DisplayName(DisplayNames.ReportName)]
    public string ReportName { get; set; }

    //Check if the reportname was entered
    private void CheckReportName()
    {
    //code to check reportname and generate the errormessage containing the colheader to be sent to grid 
    }

    private static class DisplayNames
    {
        public const string ReportName = "Report Name";
    }
}
```

This executes faster than the Reflection-based approach and (more importantly) it avoids using a hard-coded property name for getting the property to find the attribute.